# Timeout for dropped packets (UDP)

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, timeout, packet

I'm trying to create a timeout using `select()` for UDP socket transfer. I want to send an `int` from `client` to `server`, wait 300ms, and if I don't get an ACK, resend the packet. I'm not sure how to set this up properly with the timeout. From what I've gathered online and on the notes I have from class, `select` should be used on the receiving end.

the client at the server send back and forth the numbers 1-100. I have a separate `router` simulated code that randomly drops packets

Here is the code i have for the client side

```
int sent = 1;
int received = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        string sent1 = to_string(sent);
        char const *pchar = sent1.c_str();
        if(!sendto(s, pchar, sizeof(pchar), 0, (struct  sockaddr*) &sa_in, sizeof(sa_in)))
            cout << "send NOT successful\n";
        else
        {
            cout << "Client sent " << sent << endl;
            sent++;
        }
        // receive
        fd_set readfds; //fd_set is a type
        FD_ZERO(&readfds); //initialize 
        FD_SET(s, &readfds); //put the socket in the set

        if(!(outfds = select (1 , &readfds, NULL, NULL, & timeouts))) 
            break;
        if (outfds == 1) //receive frame
        {
            if (!recvfrom(s, buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &client_length))
                cout << "receive NOT successful\n";
            else
            {
                received = atoi(buffer2);
                cout << "Client received " << received << endl;
                received++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is identical for the receiving side except it is in reverse: receive first, then send

My code doesn't utilize the timeout at all. This is basically what I want to do:

```
send packet(N)
    if (timeout)
        resend packet(N)
    else
        send packet(N+1)
```

Comment: Udp stands for *Unreliable* datagram Protocol. It doesn't do acks or resends. You have to implement that yourself. The send timeout here is for pushing the packet onto the wire or the network stack discarding it.

Answer (score 2):

If the receiver gets a timeout it needs to tell the sender, or else *not* tell the sender. In other words you have to implement either a NACK-based protocol or an ACK-based protocol.